# Formatting SOLR response

Tags: json, solr, nested

I have a query returning following, which is standard output of SOLR.

```
{
    Company : "Nokia"
    Series : "X"
    Products : ["3320", "1100"]
    ProductStatus : ["Continued","Discontinued"]
}
```

I want to format the output as follows

```
{
    Company : "Nokia"
    Series : "X"
    Products : [{
        "name": "3320", 
        "Status":"Continued"
    },
    {
        "name":"1100",
        "Status":"Discontinued"
    }]
}
```

How to achieve above?

Comment: you should consider do it on the client side, not the Solr. While it's possible to do a custom response writer it would lead to more problems like supporting, deploying custom code, etc. It won't benefit from it

Comment: In addition, creating a small middle layer that does this for you would also be possible - i.e. your service contacts a small service between your application and Solr that builds the structure you want. We've used this previously with good results.